# Two Ways to Handle a Request - Just Written Differently

Tags: django

I was looking at some different code on github and came across something that was confusing. Is there any differences between the code below?

```
class RandomView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(self.request, 'random_template.html)
```

Versus

```
class RandomView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'random_template.html)
```

To me this would do the same thing but to be fair my knowledge is pretty limited. Is one considered bad practice? Or maybe just preference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> They point to the same object. self.request is assigned in the factory
> function that is returned from View.as_view(). I would guess that the
> reason for passing the request argument explicitly is to make it
> easier to convert between class based views and function views. And it
> also makes it more clear that methods such as get uses the request
> object.
>
> I recommend that you follow the convention from the django source code
> and examples in the docs, and use the request that is passed as an
> argument instead of self.request.

[found this answer on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/965oni/difference_between_request_and_selfrequest_in/)

Comment: Oh wow cool thank you very much. I didn't see this while googling and this satisfied my curiosity!